# Custom shortcuts to folders in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Mac OS X offers some handy keyboard shortcuts in the Finder to the Desktop, Applications-folder etc.

Is there a way to make your own shortcuts to certain folders? There is software that does this, namely Default Folder X - but it would be cool if it could be done without installing software.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're looking for when you say "shortcuts".

- You can drag folders into the "Places" section of your Finder Sidebar which act as a "Shortcut" to a folder which is nested deeper in the file system.
- When in a Save Dialog you can press <kbd>/</kbd> to get a file path for saving your file in whatever folder you want.
- From within Finder you can press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to get a filepath window which will take you to whatever folder you want.
- You can create a symbolic link using the `ln -s` command in terminal to generate an "alias" file which let you have a "shortcut" to folders nested deep in the filesystem from your desktop or someplace easy like that.

The way you worded your question it's not clear that any of these options are what you're looking for.